# Selenium Continuous Integration with Team Services

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

I have a set of Selenium tests in a test project within my solution, and they run just fine from within Visual Studio. However, when I check in code and they run as part of my continuous integration build profile, they fail.

A brief explanation of the setup:
1) Code is checked into the build agent server.

2) The project is then built, and then deployed to server 2 (which is remote from the build server).

3) Unit tests then run.

Here is an example unit test:

```
public void Login_InvalidAccessUrl_ShowMesage()
{
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://testsite.company.com/Login");
    IWebElement el = driver.FindElementById("invalidAccessUrlSection");
    Assert.AreNotEqual(el, null);
}
```

This runs beautifully from Visual Studio, but when CI runs the same tests, I get the following:

```
Error Message:
Test method eNotify.Staff.Tests.SeleniumTests.Login_InvalidAccessUrl_ShowMesage threw exception:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:11570/session timed out after 60 seconds. ---> System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
TestCleanup method eNotify.Staff.Tests.SeleniumTests.Dispose threw exception. System.NullReferenceException: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
Stack Trace:
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest request)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor(ChromeOptions options)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver..ctor()
at eNotify.Staff.Tests.SeleniumTests.Login_InvalidAccessUrl_ShowMesage()
TestCleanup Stack Trace
at eNotify.Staff.Tests.SeleniumTests.Dispose()
```

Am I missing a driver or some software? As far as I know, there is nothing listening on port 11570.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure the VSTS agent is running as Interactive process.

Secondly, adding no-sanbox argument to ChromeDrive instance. For example:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks - it was the no-sandbox argument which got it all working.